# Find and replace searching all files in xCode using sed

Tags: xcode, bash, replace, sed, find

I have files that I often drop into Xcode that are made in another program where I need to replace one string.  I would just like it to be part of the build phases as a script.  I tried using find with sed like

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/onclick="js(setPanoName(/onloaded="js(setPanoName(/g' {} \;
```

With no effect. I know it's really close. What's wrong?

Comment: works perfectly for me (GNU/Linux)

Comment: The problem is that the files aren't showing changes.  I see that they've changed on one occasion, but I'm not sure how. Tried running again, quitting, going back in and no changes were made.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my command to

```
sed -i '' 's/onclick="js(setPanoName(/onloaded="js(setPanoName(/g' *.xml;
```

And it works now.

Comment: yeah, classical quirk of `sed`. MacOS ?

Comment: use gnu sed from Macports if you want a command that's more cross platform.